# run crontab as www-data to create a file with www-data as owner

Tags: cron, debian, file-permissions

I want to run a crontab command every 5 mins that executes a py script.
The py script inturn generates a log file  with midnight rotation within /var/www/logs/.The logs dir has 777 permission.

The log file has midnight rotation and when new file is created,it creates as root owner.How to ensure the ownership stays as www-data as some other scripts also write to the same file and having root ownership causes permission issue for other scripts.

One way is to put the command in,

`crontab -u www-data -e`

This works fine, but i want to maintain all my cron commands under root user.

I tried doing the same with sudo, but it creates with root as owner which not what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a good solution for this problem.

Now I am using FACL in linux to set default permissions to all the files created in the logs directory.This way i can run all my crons in root.
[here is more on facl in linux](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/unix-linux-access-control-lists-acls-basics/)

Also as mentioned in question, running crons under www-data caused few other logging related problems.

I used below command to set facl.

```
setfacl -m default:u:www-data:rw logs
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding ` && chown -R www-data

Comment: I gave a crude example.Sorry, I have rephrased my question.

Comment: not quite sure. maybe you running python script as a root causing log file to have root owner.

Comment: yea...py script is run by the above mentioned root users cron.

Comment: you can use `os.chown()` in python or run script as www-data user or create another script that chowns files afterwards.

Comment: Managing this in the script is not suitable option for me as the same must work on other platforms without any change.